# Use Java to start a Windows exe

Tags: java, windows, native, runtime.exec

I want to find out how to open any exe in Windows using Java code. I have searched Google before and they only show me part of the code that they use, I think, because it doesn't seem to compile.

I have downloaded JDK 7 to compile. I don't use Eclipse at the moment and also explaining what I had to do to get it to work in detail would help a lot.

to what Sri Harsha Chilakapati said: would i need to create a class for the code?

Thanks to those who answered but i didn't quite get what you meant but i did however  manage to find a website which had what i was after: 
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "\"c:/program files/windows/notepad.exe\"");
p.waitFor();
  } 
}
```

the above was what i was after but thanks again anyway to the people who answered.

Comment: see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: If your code doesn't compile, it would be in  your best interest to post it here along with any error messages so we can comment on what you can do to possibly make it work.

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
String myExe = "C:\\MyExe.exe";
String args  = "";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myExe + " " + args);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are better (more robust to spaces, say) ways to pass args than just concatenating `args` to `myExe`.  See the other `exec` methods in `Runtime`.

Comment: Better yet, `"C:/MyExe.exe"`. The "\\" path separator is for Windows. However, "/" works in all operating systems.

Comment: Myself, I'd use a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparator for path separator. You can have the right one for your platform without any assumptions.

Comment: @user1168261 He said perfectly that it's windows and hence there's no need for your path separator

Comment: @ Sri Harsha Chilakapati Thats true, but JRunner suggested "/" because it works on all platforms. I just wanted to point out that there is the pathSepartor for all platforms.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati and the OP's next question will be 'why doesn't this work platform X". Despite what the OP said, user1168261's comment is the correct method for approaching this kind of problem, IMHO - personally, I'd use File.seperator, but that's me

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), especially for additional arguments.

Comment: ProcessBuilder is a better approach than runtime, but you really need to flesh this out with an example so that it is useful to someone with this question. Because they're asking this question it's a safe bet they're not already familiar with process builder.