# Executing command line app

Tags: java

I am trying to execute JAD decompiler on class file from code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\1\\jad.exe c:\\1\\EIn.class");
//All paths are correct, "c:\\1\\jad.exe c:\\1\\EIn.class" wotks when I run it in cmd
```

When I debug i don't get any errors, debugger moves to the next line...

if I put:

```
int res = p.waitFor();
```

It just hangs.

Update:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
String str = null;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) { //Stucks here
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433888/use-java-to-start-a-windows-exe/12433899#12433899

Comment: what should i see there?

Comment: I don't understand you. what /k argument?

Comment: Use the cmd to launch it. The '/k' arg causes to wait in the cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `jad` decompiler waiting on input from you via stdin?

To see the errors that you are getting, consume the `getOutputStream` and `getErrorStream` to see what the decompiler is writing out.

You can use the `ProcessBuilder` class to make redirecting streams a little more pleasant.

Comment: with file ProcessBuilder it also gets stuck

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String[] cmd = { "c:\\1\\jad.exe", "-c:\\1\\EIn.class" };
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    p.waitFor();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a TRAP in Java ,please just have a look at [this page](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html),you will get more than you wanna!